# Fiind records based on duplicate data in two columns and compulsory different in the third one

Tags: sql

I have a table with housnumber, street and city. I want all the records that have the same street and housenumber but they are located in different cities.

```
| housenumber | street | city |
| 12          | Pop  | Berlin |
| 12          | Pop  | Berlin |
| 12          | Pop  | Paris  |
| 12          | Pop  | Viena  |
| 12          | Lup  | Viena  |
| 32          | Mop  | Zagreb |
| 45          | Tuu  | Zagreb |
| 49          | Tuu  | Zagreb |
```

The result should be

```
| 12          | Pop  | Berlin |
| 12          | Pop  | Paris  |
| 12          | Pop  | Viena  |
```

I tried the inner join but it returns a huge amount of data.

```
SELECT
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2  
ON t1.street  = t2.street 
and t1.housenumber = t2.housenumber 
WHERE t1.city != t2.city;
```

Comment: Your table includes several 12 Pop Berlin rows. Try `SELECT DISTINCT` and see if that helps.

Comment: BTW, tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with Select DISTINCT but keep return the duplicates too.

Comment: Correct your query above, copy-and-paste error?

Answer (score 1):

The below query is working for what you required. See the attached link for proof,

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.housenumber, t1.street, t1.city
FROM tablename t1
INNER JOIN tablename t2  
  ON t1.street = t2.street 
  AND t1.housenumber = t2.housenumber 
  AND t1.city != t2.city;
```

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uelVQ.png)

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vrpq.png)